# Protractors waitForAngular and angularfire/firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, protractor, angularfire

From my understanding, waitForAngular is executed on each step, and it waits for any kind of angular rendering and/or $http calls before proceeding to the next step.

My problem I am having is, I'm using Angularfire/Firebase as my backend, and in my tests when I click on a button for example - the waitForAngular is executed too fast, and then next step has occured before firebase has come back with a result.

Does anyone know a simple way to extend waitForAngular to *also* wait for any Angularfire call?. That would solve my problem and I could get rid of all of these dreaded sleep calls.

Comment: It is correct, waitForAngular is executed as long as you haven't modified the default `browser.ignoreSynchronization` value. Protractor should be waiting for any $http backend, if is not then is a bug and I suggest you to setup a small working example of your failure then submit an issue [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/new).

Comment: Did you check out the AngularFire e2e tests? They all utilize Protractor and have resolved the same issues you've described.

Comment: @Kato AFAICS the AngularFire e2e tests just use sleep

Answer (score 1):

If you're using something like this

```
element(by.css('.btn')).click()
ptor.waitForAngular();
//execute something after
```

You can try converting it to a nested `promise resolve` pattern like this

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('.btn')).click().then(function(){
   //execute something after
});
```

I only have some basic info about `firebase` but haven't used it ever. But I guess this should help with promises/http requests.